# Research on exact-cover problem and graph theory for NP-complete problems?

Tags: complexity-theory, graphs, np-complete

Sorry for the vagueness, but I'm trying to study the latest progress on the exact cover problem and using graphs for NP-complete problems. Googling around has not been very helpful. I understand the basics but I can't find a key journal in this area or where to look online. Any references would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'm afraid your question is too vague. Graphs are usually not "used for NP-complete problems", but rather some problems are modeled as graphs and then perhaps proven to be computationally difficult. There are no key journals in this sense, but rather there are journals for say theoretical computer science (sometimes using graphs) and say pure graph theory (mostly from a mathematical perspective).